# How can I include HTML, CSS and Javascript into my PHP code?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm having a parse error appear when I try to include my HTML, CSS and Javascript code into my PHP.

The problem causing it is the ' ' as in `document.getElementById('video').src` or `style="background-image: url('.$id..png');`

Here's the code i'm trying to fix.

```
$videosHTML = '<a onclick="document.getElementById('video').src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$link.'?rel=0'; document.getElementById('videoName').innerHTML = '.$Name.';"><div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url('.$id..png');"><p class="title">'.$Name.'</p><p class="time">'.$Time.'</p></div></a>' . $videosHTML;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a number of ways to use inline strings in your code.

The simplest are single quotes `'` and double quotes `"`. The difference is the amount of interpretation that goes on inside the strings. The single quotes have the minimum possible, but they will still react to being closed (by a single quote).

So if you want to use a single quote inside a single quoted string, you have to escape it. You do that by adding a backslash in front of the single quote e.g.: `$str='abc\'def';` .

Inside single quotes there's only 2 things that get expanded: `\'` become a `'` and `\\` becomes `\`. All the rest, including stuff like `\n` just remains as you typed it.

Inside double quotes a lot more is expanded. E.g. `\"` becomes a `"`, `\n` becomes a newline, variables are expanded, and much more (see link below).

In addition to those there's also heredoc and nowdoc. The difference between those two is like the difference between the single quotes and the double quotes above. Essentially you define the END tag yourself.

All of these print the same:

```
$var='foo';
print('single:\' double:" var:'.$var.' newline:'."\n");
print("single:' double:\" var:$var newline:\n");
print(<<<END
single:' double:" var:$var newline:

END
);
```

PHP strings manual is at: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Actually, there's one more way to declare a string, but it's terrible, and I can't even remember how... Edit : it's `Heredoc` and `Nowdoc`

Comment: Seblor: Agreed, as trying to keep the answer simple for new users. Will edit to try to improve for others.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed my problem. I used single quotes and double quotes as user swa66 suggested.

```html
$videosHTML = "<a onclick=" . '"document.getElementById' . "('video').src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/" . $Link . "SVCvhpkHb1A?rel=0'; document.getElementById('videoName').innerHTML = '" . $Name . "';" . '"><div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: ' . "url('thumbnails/" . $id . ".png');" . '"><p class="title">' . $Name . '</p><p class="time">' . $Time . '</p></div></a>' . $videosHTML;
```